# mongodb get users with most liked posts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

If I have a collection with documents looking more or less like this:

```
{
"_id": "52c06c86b78a091f26000001",
"desc": "Something somethingson",
"likes": [
    {
        "user_id": "52add4f4344e8ca867000001",
        "username": "asd",
        "created": 1390652212592
    },
    {
        "user_id": "52add4f4344e8ca867000001",
        "username": "asd",
        "created": 1390652212592
    }
],
"user_id": "52add4f4344e8ca867000001",
"username":"username"
}
```

Could I with mongodb (using nodejs & express) get a list of 10 users with the most liked posts?

I'm thinking it should be possible to do this Map-Reduce or with Aggregate, by grouping all posts by "user_id" and then count the total amount of items in the "likes" array. And then get the top 10 "user_id"s from that.

I'm guessing this is possible. Only problem is that I dont get the examples from the mongo website enough to put together my own thing.

Could anyone show me an example of doing this, or at least tell me its impossible if it is. =)

Comment: you need to look at the aggregation framework.  They have a very direct example applicable to your use case. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/#return-the-five-most-common-likes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try that out...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$likes"},
  {$group: {_id: "$user_id", likesCount: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$sort: {likesCount: -1}},
  {$limit: 10},
  {$project: {_id: 1}}
])
```

See this [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/#return-the-five-most-common-likes).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  However, this site is to help people learn, not to do work for them.  OP can jsut copy paste this without understanding what happened, and nothing of value was gained.

Comment: This site helps people to find solutions. If the questioner does copy paste or analyses the example step by step is his/her decision. This answer is definitely a good answer.

Comment: I am not doing anybody's work here... This is an example, at best. The OP will not create an empire from this simple query. This query is not proprietary and does not belong to me, nor does it belong to you or the OP. MongoDB created the query engine for everyone to use. Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it is possible:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$likes"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id", 
            likesPerUser: {
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    }
    {
        $sort: {
            likesPerUser: -1
        };
    }
    {
        $limit: 10
    }
])
```

Comment: In the $group clause, user_id: "$user_id" should be replaced with _id: "$user_id"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count the number of likes element per parent user, you can do the following:

http://mongotry.herokuapp.com/#?bookmarkId=52fb8c604e86f9020071ed71

```
[
{
    "$unwind": "$likes"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$user_id",
        "likesPerUser": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "likesPerUser": -1
    }
},
{
    "$limit": 10
}
]
```

Else if you need the number of liked user-id, counting 1 per sub-document cross all parents, you can do the following:

http://mongotry.herokuapp.com/#?bookmarkId=52fb8cf74e86f9020071ed72

```
[
{
    "$unwind": "$likes"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$likes.user_id",
        "likesPerUser": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "likesPerUser": -1
    }
},
{
    "$limit": 1
}
]
```